# Why is SQL Server returning a nullable bit when CASE is used?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, nullable

Assume the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST_TABLE]
(
   [TEST_VALUE] [smallint] NOT NULL
)
```

The value in the column can be 0, 1 or 2. The rationale why this can happen is irrelevant for the sake of the question.

Now, assume we create a view to encapsulate a simple query to this table:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TEST_VIEW]
AS 
SELECT RETURN_VALUE =
       CASE
           WHEN TBL.[TEST_VALUE] = 1 THEN CAST(1 as bit)
           ELSE CAST(0 as bit)
       END
FROM [dbo].[TEST_TABLE] AS [TBL]
```

After this view is created if we check what columns the view returns then the `RETURN_VALUE` column is typed as `(bit, null)` in SQL Server Management Studio, and no constructs such as wrapping the entire CASE ... END clause into a CAST() seems to change this fact.

In which scenario can the return value truly be NULL? Or is SQL Server just being extra-cautious here? Is there a way how I can enforce the view column's datatype to be `(bit, not null)`?

Comment: A hint - is `TEST_VALUE` nullable? If it takes a value of NULL, what should `RETURN_VALUE` be?

Comment: @BenThul: As stated in the table creation DDL, it's not nullable.

Comment: @Turo: Yes, the answer is sufficient to resolve my issue.

I did find a link to DBA Stack Exchange from the discussion linked to the answer you gave: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114260/why-is-a-not-null-computed-column-considered-nullable-in-a-view

This explains the situation, although I'm not using a computed column.